# Two tables with the same primary keys

Tags: primary-key

Can two tables have the same primary keys?

For instance:

[image: two tables with the same primary keys]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is a common scenario when implementing 0..1 relationships.

Comment: I guess you mean 1-1 relationships

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ 1..1 relationships are impossible in practice, at least on a current RDBMS. In a 0..1 relationships, those that have the same PK, the one that gets the 0 is the one that implements the foreign key.

Comment: OK, we mean the same thing. I just have seen (what you note as 0..1) to be noted as `0..1 - 1` and the strict 1-1 to be noted as `1-1` (and in general, all of them to be called **one-on-one**). I know that strict 1-1 is difficult - but not impossible, even with DRI only. You only need deferrable constraints, which are available in Postgres (and Oracle if I am not wrong).